# Cloud not reach Cloud Firestore backend on Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

some of my clients are facing to a trouble with this error [image: Error firebase/firestore]

There are able to login on my website but this error occurs when a query is triggered to reach my firestore database. On my side I don't have this trouble.

I found some workarounds [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71045643/could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend-react-native-firebase-v9) [link 2](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1674) [[link 3]](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1674) [link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70992830/how-to-enable-experimentalforcelongpolling-in-angular-fire)[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70992830/how-to-enable-experimentalforcelongpolling-in-angular-fire).
It seems i need to add a firestore seeting like *experimentalForceLongPolling*

I tried something like this in my environment.prod.ts

```
    import env from './.env'; 
//ENV PROD
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  version: env.npm_package_version + '-prod',
  serverUrl: '',
  defaultLanguage: 'en-US',
  supportedLanguages: ['en-US', 'fr-FR', 'es-ES'],
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true, //THIS LINE

//Base de données 'firestore' and 'realtime database' from FIREBASE => BD PROD gbl-ist-ve-dlaaas
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "myKey",
    authDomain: "xxxxx",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxx"
  }
};
```

and in my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
],
...
...
```

Is that correct way to import setting *experimentalForceLongPolling* ?

Comment: Which error are you referring to?

Comment: In the description (image)